# Is there any environment that works exactly like \begin{equation}, but without going into math-mode?

Tags: math-mode

I would like to write a sentence that is centered and numbered automatically at the end. If what I am trying to type is just an equation, `\begin{equation}` works very nicely. However, since what I write involves a lot of words, I do not want to use `\begin{equation}`. Right now, all I can think of is using `\textrm` every time I write a regular word, but there must be another solution. As we keep the automatic numbering, is there any way to do what I am trying to do?

The following is the sample. Appreciate it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\textrm{The derivative }y'\textrm{ of }y=\ln x\textrm{ is }y'=\frac{1}{x}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should type that like any other math component, only in text with interspersed math:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\vspace{\dimexpr-\abovedisplayskip+\abovedisplayshortskip}% May be needed
\begin{equation}
  \text{The derivative $y'$ of $y = \ln x$ is $y' = \tfrac{1}{x}$.}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

You may wish to use a shorter space above, depending on the `\abovedisplayshortskip` depending on how the previous paragraph ends.

Comment: This works great as well. Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `\mbox` inside `equation`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % recommended for math

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\mbox{The derivative $f'(x)$ of $f(x)=\log x$ is $f'(x)=\dfrac{1}{x}$}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```